# Issue with dates in statsmodels and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a pandas dataframe object that is indexed by a timestamp.  I am trying to fit an AR model from statsmodels with the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxx')
model=tsa.ar_model.AR(df['price'])
```

However I am getting the error

```
ValueError: dates must be of type datetime
```

But as far as I know the dates are of the correct format.  It might also help if I show the result of printing df['price'] which is

```
 timestamp
1976-01-01 12:00:00     96541
1976-02-01 12:00:00     90103
1976-03-01 12:00:00     96541
1976-04-01 12:00:00    108112
1976-05-01 12:00:00    115855
1976-06-01 12:00:00    119712
1976-07-01 12:00:00    115855
1976-08-01 12:00:00    114550
1976-09-01 12:00:00    118407
1976-10-01 12:00:00    128702
1976-11-01 12:00:00    115855
1976-12-01 12:00:00    102979
1977-01-01 12:00:00    111969
1977-02-01 12:00:00    106836
1977-03-01 12:00:00    115594
...
2012-05-01 12:00:00    257375
2012-06-01 12:00:00    250850
2012-07-01 12:00:00    246500
2012-08-01 12:00:00    242150
2012-09-01 12:00:00    237452
2012-10-01 12:00:00    230724
2012-11-01 12:00:00    218950
2012-12-01 12:00:00    210250
2013-01-01 12:00:00    210250
2013-02-01 12:00:00    203000
2013-03-01 12:00:00    218950
2013-04-01 12:00:00    232000
2013-05-01 12:00:00    232000
2013-06-01 12:00:00    226548
2013-07-01 12:00:00    226548
```

Comment: what outputs command `df.index.dtype`?

Comment: The output is only 'object'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is stated by `df.index.dtype`, despite you regard your timestamp as a datetime, it is an object. You can easely convert it to datetime with

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have fixed that problem.  But now I have another error which says "ValueError: Currently, you need to give freq if dates are used." I suppose that "freq" is another argument that I need to include in AR().  But what does "freq" mean?

Comment: @user1893354 It's ok, and I think wiser, to start a new question, about `ar_model` usage, as the problem seems to be unrelated with current one. Wiser, as it might be of its own value, breef search didn't revealed answered relevant question. If this answer was helpful to you, you might want [consider accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: You want to update to a newer version of statsmodels, I suspect.

Comment: @alko given that I can't reproduce the error on current master (as posted in that thread), I suspect that he hasn't actually updated to master...